# abi::__cxa_demangle without dynamic memory allocation/deallocation

Tags: c++, c

I am using abi::__cxa_demangle api to demangle names returned by backtrace_symbols_fd(). I have these function calls inside a signal handler for SIGSEGV. In order to avoid memory allocation after segv in the process, I am using a custom allocater that has already allocated some memory during the start of the process. I am passing a pointer to this pre-allocated buffer as the second argument to abi::__cxa_demangle.

```
char* d = abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled, resDemangled, &len, &status);
```

Here `mangled` is the mangled name of the function, `resDemangled` is a pointer to a preallocated buffer of size 10000 in which the demangled result is expected, `len` is 10000.
The documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) says, "If output_buffer is not long enough, it is expanded using realloc".

My demangled name is less than 100 chars in size and output buffer is 10000 chars. Yet it seems some dynamic memory allocation is happening inside the function since in gdb I am reaching a line of code that is calling free (shown below) :

```
char *  __cxa_demangle (const char *mangled_name, char *output_buffer,  size_t *length, int *status) {
     ...   
     demangled = d_demangle (mangled_name, DMGL_PARAMS | DMGL_TYPES, &alc);
     ...
     if (strlen (demangled) < *length) {
         strcpy (output_buffer, demangled);
         free (demangled);
         demangled = output_buffer;
     }
     ...
 }
```

In gdb, I could not reach a line where we are malloc-ing or realloc-ing memory. My question is:

(1) Why/How heap memory allocation is happening when I am passing my output buffer as the 2nd argument to __cxa_demangle, and the buffer is large enough to hold the result?

(2) More importantly, is there an alternate/modern API that I can use in place of __cxa_demangle which does not dynamically allocate memory. Or, is there any way I can ask __cxa_demangle not to dynamically allocate memory on heap?

I am restricted to c++17 or less.

Answer (score 2):

> Why/How heap memory allocation is happening when I am passing my output buffer as the 2nd argument to __cxa_demangle, and the buffer is large enough to hold the result?

As part of the implementation of demangling, a buffer is allocated by `d_demangle`. The result is copied to the output buffer. The output buffer is not `realloc`ed because it is long enough.

`__cxa_demangle` does not promise not to allocate during its work, or generally to be signal-safe. Very little is signal-safe.

> (2) More importantly, is there an alternate/modern API that I can use in place of __cxa_demangle which does not dynamically allocate memory. Or, is there any way I can ask __cxa_demangle not to dynamically allocate memory on heap?

There are libraries like [crashpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/overview_design.md) to gather crash information. They commonly try to do this out-of-process.

> I am restricted to c++17 or less.

This lives outside the realm of standard C++.

Comment: Thanks for the information! One thing not clear to me, you mentioned "a buffer is allocated by d_demangle", which is only expected. However i could not hit a breakpoint at any malloc, then how is the memory allocation happening? which API is used? Function __cxa_demangle() is called multiple times, since there is a call to free, there must be some malloc happening too?

Comment: In gcc's libiberty (the implementation snippet from the question), __cxa_demangle calls d_demangle which calls d_growable_string_init which calls d_growable_string_resize which calls realloc (with NULL). So the allocation is happening with realloc. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/cp-demangle.c#L4277